# What is a "mere cover"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, covering-spaces

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding a definition of this. I saw this term in Stefan Wewers' thesis and it seemed familiar, but googling "mere cover" doesn't give any good results.

A definition or reference(s) would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some context for the term, or a link to the thesis?

Comment: "Mere" is probably being used in its ordinary English meaning rather than as a technical term. It's hard to say without context. Can you quote the paragraph in which it appears or something?